# facebook API: any public way to get the count of followers for a specific page within a global page hierarchy?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the facebook API, for a page, `fan_count` gives the number of users who like the Page. For Global Pages this is the count for all Pages across the brand. ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) To get the specific count of fans of a particular global page (not the sum across the brand), we have used /{page-id}/insights/page_fans_country to get the count of followers of the specific page, via this public insights metric.

I see that "starting on February 5th, 2018, a Page access token with the read_insights permission will be required for Page-owned Post insights" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/insights) -- including the two metrics that have long been public, page_fans_country and page_storytellers_by_country.

Moving forward, is there any other public way to get the count of followers for a specific page within a global page hierarchy, i.e. without having a read_insights token for the page?

I see the `country_page_likes` field for pages, but it doesn't seem to be publically available either (requires a token with, i believe, admin access).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not publicly available, unfortunately!